# Existence of nontrivial transfinite divisibility in $R$-modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, noncommutative-algebra, noncommutative-rings

Let $R$ be a unital, possibly noncommutative ring and $s \in R$. For a right $R$-module $M$, define $Ms = \{ms \mid m \in M\}$; this is an additive subgroup of $M$, which is a module over the centralizer of $s$. For an ordinal $\alpha$, define $Ms^\alpha$ by transfinite induction: $Ms^0 = M$, $Ms^{\alpha+1} = (Ms^\alpha)s$, and take intersections at limit ordinals. Then the the groups $Ms^\alpha$ must stabilize eventually; say that the *$s$-divisibility rank* of $M$ is the minimal $\alpha$ such that $Ms^\alpha = Ms^{\alpha+1}$. Consider the following conditions:

1. For some $s \in R$, the $s$-divisibility rank of $R \in Mod_R$ is infinite (i.e. $R$ is not strongly $\pi$-regular).
2. For some $s \in R$ and some $M \in Mod_R$, the $s$-divisibility rank of $M$ is infinite.
3. For some $s \in R$, there exist right $R$-modules of arbitrarily large $s$-divisibility rank.

Obviously, $3 \Rightarrow 2 \Leftrightarrow 1$. I suspect that 1,2,3 are equivalent, and I think I can show this when $R$ is commutative, via a sort of "generalized Prufer module" construction. But I'm not sure when $R$ is noncommutative.

**Question 1:** Does $1 \Rightarrow 3$ when $R$ is noncommutative?

There is another condition which these appear to be related to. Let $m \in M$ and $n \in N$ be two elements of right $R$-modules. Say that $m \in M, n \in N$ are *weakly equivalent* if there exist maps of right $R$-modules $f: M \to N$ and $g: N \to M$ such that $f(m) = n$ and $g(n) = m$. This is an equivalence relation on elements of right $R$-modules. Consider the condition:

4. There exists a proper class of elements of right $R$-modules, no two of which are weakly equivalent.

Because $f(Ms^\alpha) \subseteq N s^\alpha$ for every map of right $R$-modules $f: M \to N$, we have that $3 \Rightarrow 4$.

**Question 2:** Does $4 \Rightarrow 3$?

The related question of whether $4 \Rightarrow 1$, can be stated contrapositively as: if $R$ is strongly $\pi$-regular, then does $R$ have only a set of weak equivalence classes of elements of $R$-modules?